# Fragment Shader - Reproduce blue channel level output slider

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Im trying to create a fragment shader that will do the same job as the photoshop levels output slider. I would like to do this on a specific channel (in this case blue).

I have the code as below:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

#define GammaCorrection(color, gamma)       pow(color, vec3(1.0/gamma))

#define LevelsControlOutputRange(color, minOutput, maxOutput) mix(vec3(minOutput/255), vec3(maxOutput/255), color)


void main()
{

     lowp vec4 texel = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

     lowp vec3 outputColor;
     outputColor.rgb = texel.rgb;

     lowp vec3 pass3 = LevelsControlOutputRange(outputColor,200,255); 

     lowp vec4 pass4;
     pass4.r = outputColor.r;
     pass4.g = outputColor.g;
     pass4.b = pass3.b;

 gl_FragColor = pass4;


}
```

This has no effect on the resulting image so i think that i may have to do more with the line:

```
pass4.b = pass3.b;
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mix` takes a value between 0…1 as the mixing parameter. Your 255 will be clamped to 1 and therefore you'll always get the max output value. In a similar fashion texture values are in the range 0…1 to you must not divide by 255 to get into some range! BTW: Simply dividing by 255 is not correct – details here http://kaba.hilvi.org/programming/range/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply datenwolf im using the macro as defined here: http://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/levels-control-shader/ here he divides the value by 255, is that not correct?

Comment: @Skeep: The server with the source code seems down, but in the article there's not divide by 255. Maybe the shader code uses integer textures, which would be weird. Anyway: You shouldn't use a macro for this. Use a function. Macros are meant for things that don't fit well into functions, like repetetive tasks performed on and with the local data of a function.